# How can I define default route parameters in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm building a multi languages site using Laravel 5.

I knew that in Laravel, I can define `prefix` for route like:

```
http://domain/en/users/1
http://domain/en/shop/1
```

And in Middleware, I can get the segment of url path to detect the language and set locale of current Request.

But I can't find anyway to add lang parameter in default for route like folowings:

```
http://domain/users/1?lang=en
http://domain/shop/1?lang=en
```

Or are there anyways to hook into route function of Framework to append default parameter `?lang=ja`into all route when I call ?
(ja is current locale of application which was set in middleware before  )

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can create a middleware that sets up a default 'lang' query parameter if the request doesn't have one. It will work for all the requests to your app, so you can get the lang parameter in every route handler.

Create a middleware LangFilter in the console (while in the project directory) :

```
php artisan make:middleware LangFilter
```

Then open up `./app/Http/Kernel.php` and add :

```
\App\Http\Middleware\LangFilter::class
```

to the `$middleware` array. Now open up the middleware you created, i.e `./app/Http/Middleware/LangFilter.php` and add the checking and setting code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class LangFilter
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Checks for lang in the parameters.
        if($request->input('lang') == null) {
            // Adds the default one since it doesn't have one.
            $request->merge(array('lang' => 'en'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

If you want to have this kind of filtering for just a subset of all the routes you have, you need to register the middleware differently in Kernel.php.

**UPDATE**

For making a helper that generates routes with current locale :

- Create a folder app/Support.
- Create the helpers file app/Support/helpers.php
- Open up **helpers.php**, and add this code to add the helper :

  ```
  <?php
    function locale_route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true) {
      return route($name, array_merge($parameters, [
        'lang' => App::getLocale()
        ]), $absolute);
    }
  ?>
  ```
- Add the helpers file to composer autoload in **composer.json**:

  ```
  "autoload" : {
    "files" : [
      "app/Support/helpers.php"
    ]
  }
  ```
- Now run in the console :

  ```
   composer dumpautoload
  ```

Now you can call `locale_route` with the same parameters you give to `route` to create urls that has the current locale added in query params.

Comment: Yeah ! I used middleware to detect lang parameters from client. 
And I want to find a way which I can add it from default.

for example.
If  current locale is ja , 
   when I calle route('users.show',[id=1]),  It will generate `http://domain/users/1?lang=ja`
and the next request  middleware will dected lang and set app current locale is ja  again.

Comment: Is it really necessary ? I mean whether the link has a lang param or not, before the request hits your controller/route handler, lang will be set either by default or if the link has one explicitly. Also, you said you used a middleware to detect the lang param, but the above middleware detects and adds a default one if there isn't one.

Comment: When I call route('ROUTE_NAME');  route function create the link which is configured in routes.php  without query parameter.
For example: 

 route('user.show',[id=>'1']) will generate http://domain/user/show/1 

I'm finding a way to add lang parameter = App::getLocale to queryString of all links like followings:
 route('user.show',[id=>'1']) will generate 

 http://domain/user/show/1?lang=ja 
or
  http://domain/user/show/1?lang=en 

basing on current App Locale

Comment: I have checked the method definition of `route` method in `UrlGenerator` of the framework, you can merge a lang param in there so all generated routes will have one. But that is going to be a really bad solution, I mean messing up with the internals just to get something this trivial right, and the vendor folder (where the framework core lies) isn't even committed to your repo. I have checked on helpers, I think it's a great idea to have something like `locale_route(<name>, <params)` that will generate a route with current lang appended. Will that be okay for you ?

Comment: You can then simply wrap up the normal `route` with `locale_route`. `route` remains clean.

Comment: I'm thinking about locale_route instead of route. Or something like a new ServiceProvider in my app. 

For locale_route helper, where should I place it in L5?

In Rails, I can define the route which have customize query params in default. I was surprised that L5 doesn't support it

Comment: I'm not familiar with ServiceProvider (will check it), but I will update my answer to show how to add a `locale_route` helper. You can check this too : http://laravel.io/forum/02-03-2015-best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5. Also why not ask the same question in there (laravel.io forum) too ? The aren't much answers to this question so far.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. [Generating a route with a query string parameter](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/generating-a-route-with-a-query-string-parameter)

Comment: Thanks ! 
I knew it before. I want to find the way which I can add query string in default